# Confusion related to predictive distribution of gaussian processes

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have this confusion related to the predictive distribution of gaussian process

[image]

I didn't get how the integration gave that result. What is P(u*|x*,u). Also how come the covariance of the posterior distribution is $\sigma^2(\sigma^2I+K)^{-1}K$

Comment: Which book or where did you get this clip from?